# How to use an abbreviated vector to match a vector with a full name

Tags: r

```
tableA$area = c("太原市尖草坪区","安庆市宜秀区","北京市大兴区")
tableB$locate = c("尖草坪区", "宜秀区", "大兴区")
```

I need to combine tableA and tableB by c("area" = "locate"). How can I realize it?

Comment: Please use English so that ppl not knowing this script may also understand.

Comment: Maybe `grep` to find where are the matches and use this result to join the tables.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `tableB$locate` always contains the part of `tableA$area` after 市, you can use a regex to match everything after 市 and use this for the join:

```
tableA <- data.frame(
  other_col = 1:3,
  area = c("太原市尖草坪区","安庆市宜秀区","北京市大兴区")
)

tableB <- data.frame(
  type_col = c("A", "B", "C"),
  locate = c("尖草坪区", "宜秀区", "大兴区")
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

merged_table <- tableA %>% 
  mutate(area_wo_city = str_extract(area, "(?<=市).*$")) %>% 
  left_join(tableB, by = c("area_wo_city" = "locate"))

merged_table
  other_col           area area_wo_city type_col
1         1 太原市尖草坪区     尖草坪区        A
2         2   安庆市宜秀区       宜秀区        B
3         3   北京市大兴区       大兴区        C
```

---

## Edit

Your new data makes it harder, because now the regex has to allow to match other characters in `area` that are not contained in `locate`. Therefore, I create a regex pattern for every entry in `locate` that matches other characters in between. Then, I use these patterns to see in which row of `tableA` it matches and join based on this information. The solution works for your provided data, but I think it is quite hacky and could break for more complex situations. Also, I assume that 桓/恒 is a typo, otherwise I don't know any solutions in R to account for it.

```
tableA <- data.frame(
  other_col = 11:15,
  area = c("太原市尖草坪区","安庆市宜秀区","北京市大兴区","桓仁满族自治县","银川市西夏区")
)

tableB <- data.frame(
  type_col = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E"),
  locate = c("尖草坪区", "宜秀区", "大兴区","桓仁县","银川市西夏区")
)

library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

generate_pattern <- function(x) {
  pattern <- str_extract_all(x, boundary("character"))[[1]]
  pattern <- paste0(pattern, ".*")
  pattern <- paste0(pattern, collapse = "")
  pattern <- substr(pattern, start = 1, stop = nchar(pattern) - 2)
  pattern
}

# generate the regex pattern and search in which row in tableA it matches
tableB <- tableB %>% 
  mutate(pattern = purrr::map_chr(locate, generate_pattern),
         match_in_A = str_which(tableA$area, pattern))

tableB
  type_col       locate                                                                      pattern match_in_A
1        A     尖草坪区                           <U+00BC>.*a.*2.*Y.*<U+00C6>.*o.*<U+00C7>.*<U+00F8>          1
2        B       宜秀区                                 ò.*<U+00CB>.*D.*<U+00E3>.*<U+00C7>.*<U+00F8>          2
3        C       大兴区                                        ′.*ó.*D.*<U+00CB>.*<U+00C7>.*<U+00F8>          3
4        D       桓仁县                                 <U+00BB>.*<U+00B8>.*è.*ê.*<U+00CF>.*<U+00D8>          4
5        E 银川市西夏区 ò.*<U+00F8>.*′.*¨.*ê.*D.*<U+00CE>.*÷.*<U+00CF>.*<U+00C4>.*<U+00C7>.*<U+00F8>          5

# merge based on the matched row numbers
merged_table <- tableA %>% 
  tibble::rowid_to_column() %>% 
  left_join(tableB, by = c("rowid" = "match_in_A")) %>% 
  select(-c(rowid, pattern))

merged_table
  other_col           area type_col       locate
1        11 太原市尖草坪区        A     尖草坪区
2        12   安庆市宜秀区        B       宜秀区
3        13   北京市大兴区        C       大兴区
4        14 桓仁满族自治县        D       桓仁县
5        15   银川市西夏区        E 银川市西夏区
```

Comment: You picked up a separator "市"  and offered a simple and smart solution.

Comment: tableA$area = c("太原市尖草坪区","安庆市宜秀区","北京市大兴区","桓仁满族自治县","银川市西夏区")；tableB$locate = c("尖草坪区", "宜秀区", "大兴区","恒仁县","银川市西夏区")         .How can I combine tableA and tableB by c("area" = "locate") ?

Comment: Sorry, I think for the penultimate entry/example there is no easy solution. Is it deliberate that in A it's 桓 while in B it's 恒? If yes, then I wouldn't know of anything to do this in R, otherwise there might be a solution

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in spelling. Thank starja very much for help .But I still have a problem.In fact, tableA$area has more elements than tableB$locate and I need to keep all information in tableA. so I have to use left_join(tableA, tableB, by = c(" area"="locate").

Comment: ok, then maybe try out @Zhiqiang Wang's method, maybe this suits your data better

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you could also try something like this using @starja's `tableA` and `tableB`.

First, generate a unique identifiers (`id`) using `locate` in `TableB` by removing 区 and 县. Then, find `id` strings in `tableA` and add a variable `id` too. Finally, join `tableA` with `tableB` with `by = "id"`.

```
library(tidyverse)
tableB$id = str_remove_all(tableB$locate, "区|县")
find <- paste(unique(tableB$id), collapse="|")
tableA$id <- str_extract_all(tableA$area, find, simplify = TRUE)[,1]
left_join(tableA, tableB, by = "id")
```

Comment: also a smart solution; good to see someone with better Mandarin skills addressing the issue!

Comment: Thank Zhiqiang Wang very much for help.